# this is about spring mvc project action or result dosent find issue

Tags: java, spring-mvc, struts2

[image]this is my sample struts file code 
`

```
<package name="default" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">
    <action name="addCustomerAction" 

        class="customerAction" method="addCustomer" >
        <result name="success">customer.jsp</result>
    </action>
    <action name="listCustomerAction"
        class="customerAction" method="listCustomer" >
        <result name="success">customer.jsp</result>
    </action>

</package>
```

`
I think I mapped this correctly but there is a error occur like this

```
Could not find action or result
```

There is no Action mapped for namespace / and action name . - [unknown location]

Comment: it would be helpful if you can post the full stack trace of the exception or error.

Comment: I uploaded the screen shot in execption error

Comment: You're not requesting any of the actions you have listed in the config file.

Comment: Spring mvc tag?